# Xamarin how to remove extra space at bottom on iOS

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Anyone know how to get rid of the bottom white space which shows up on iOS only (android is fine). Here is a basic grid which should put the red row 2 at the bottom of the page but it doesn't.

Code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{OnIdiom Phone='50', Tablet='90'}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Color="Blue"/>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Color="Green"/>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Color="Red"/>

</Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[screenshot on ios (has white space on bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc1wC.png)

[screenshot on android (no white space)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8p3.png)

Other things I've tried: using an absolute layout as well as adding a stack layout to the bottom with verticaloptions=end but it resulted in the same thing--extra space on iOS yet worked on android.

Comment: I have used the same code at my end (iPhone 14 Pro simulator) and I am not getting white space in iOS. Can you please provide detail of device you are testing this code on and also which Xamarin.Forms version are you using ?

Comment: I have also test your code and not getting the white space in iOS, see [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dtk0.png). I guess your app is a Shell based app and have you set `Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"`? Can you help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post?

Comment: Very weird that you all are not seeing the extra white space, the above code is the only thing I'm adding after creating a flyout template xamarin forms mobile app so it should be all that's needed for a reproducible example. I'm testing on iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.2 simulator, xamarin forms version 5.0.0.2196

Comment: @jess Thanks for the response, I can reproduce the issue when creating a flyout template. To fix it, you can check my below posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the extra white space at the bottom of screen on Xamarin iOS, you need to set `ios:Page.UseSafeArea` to `false` like below:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             Title="Home"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="false">
    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alexandar, that works for me as well--however do you know if removing the safe space restriction will have unexpected impacts on some devices?

Comment: I don't think there's any unexpected impacts if you set `ios:Page.UseSafeArea` to `false`. You can refer to [iOS, iPadOS safe areas](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/layout#iOS-iPadOS-safe-areas) for more details.

Comment: @jess Thanks for the response, have a great day!